# Adober Reader X Fails to load PDF in Internet Explorer

Tags: adobe-reader, internet-explorer-7

We have updated our PCs to Adobe Reader X 10.0.1 from the last 9.x version.  As a part of our normal business process our users view and consume pdfs from our website through their web browser.

The problem is now that we've upgraded to Adobe Reader X users are sporadically having issues where the pdf appears to load by switching to the gray back ground of the adobe reader, but fails to load the PDF. From what I've found the Adobe Reader - Internet Explorer plugin gets hung up or crashes, because all pdfs that the user tries to open after the initial fail will also fail.  To resolve this the user must close all instances of IE and reopen IE before they can view another pdf with IE.

My research of this issue has led me to find that you can change Adobe to always open in unprotected mode, and also try to change the adobe internet option settings to a higher speed and remove the download calculation piece.  All these I have tried without success.

The only thing that I know works is uninstalling Adobe Reader X and reverting to version 9.x, which is not the best option.

Has anyone else experienced this, and found a viable solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue; see [the Adobe support page](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-opens-grey-screen-browser.html). (This isn't specifically for the version you stated you had, but the issue is the same)

There is a patch [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/kb/en/930/cpsid_93026/attachments/AdobeAcrobatReaderPatch10.1.2_cpsid_93026.zip). Download the archive, extract, run the executable and reboot.

Also, you probably want to update Reader; 10.0.1 is quite out of date.

Comment: Appreciate the response I will give this a try.